# Ruby Logger rotation on CentOs

Tags: ruby, logging

I´m doing some tests with default ruby Logger
and I´m getting this error on file rotation

> log rotation inter-process lock failed. Text file busy @
>   rb_file_s_rename - (file.log, file.log.0) 
>   log writing failed. closed stream 
>   log shifting failed. closed stream

My environment. 
   CentOS 7.2.1511
   Ruby: 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1

Note:

This error only occurs on CentOS with ruby versions after 2.0.0. With ruby 2.0.0 works fine!

I made some tests using Ubuntu with all ruby versions after 1.9 and 
this error not occurs.

Here my test code

```
require 'logger'

begin
    puts "Starting test"

    # rotate when file size equals 20kb keeping 3 old logs
    log = Logger.new("file.log", 3, 20000)
    while true
        puts "Logging..."

        log.info "info"
        log.error "error"
        log.warn "warn"
        log.debug "debug"

        sleep(1)
    end


rescue  Interrupt => _
   puts  "Exiting..."
end
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why not use something more generic and system-level like [`logrotate`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)?

Comment: thanks for your reply @tadman
Actually I'm using logrotate on our servers
This is just a test and can't understand why this occurs

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You might want to file an issue or ticket with the Logger team.